# Alternate tool for WSE 3.0

Tags: c#

I am working in application upgrading  project. Previously web services build by Web Services Enhancement 3.0 to build a web services in Visual Studio 2005. Is there alternate for Web Services Enhancement 3.0 to build a web services in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything that WSE 3.0 could do that WCF cannot do.  This link might help get you up to speed:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732008(v=vs.110).aspx